# How can I use Google Translate via Ajax using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-translate

I am using [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) via jQuery, and I am trying to translate using the [Google Translate Service](http://www.google.de/language_tools?hl=en). The service does not seem to work for me.

What am I doing wrong? How would I go about using this in my web application?

Comment: This sounds a lot like a troubleshooting question.  If you gave more information, you could get a lot better help.  Maybe config settings or a loose architecture description.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this:

```
$.ajax({  
    url: 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/language/translate',  
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: { q: 'Hello world!',  // text to translate
            v: '1.0',
            langpair: 'en|es' },   // '|es' for auto-detect
    success: function(result) {
        alert(result.responseData.translatedText);
    },  
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, errorMsg, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorMsg);
    }  
});
```

Comment: This will now throw this response: Please use Translate v2.  See http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/overview.html Version 2 is now 100% paid service.

Answer (score 2):

Translate API from Google Translate v1.0 is not working anymore, v2.0 is what are you looking for and is not for free like google search or other services from them.

The price is 20$ for 1 million characters translated.

[Here is the official info!](https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/pricing?hl=ro&csw=1)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are following the wrong strategy. You don't make AJAX calls to the Google Translate Service directly, the Google Translate Javascript API wraps this all for you.

Look at the examples in the API playground.

Comment: Maybe you don't want to include google's javascript files when already using jQuery and can do it in a few lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

What are some of the differences between your code and [Google's example code](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlanguage/documentation/#Examples)?

Do the examples work for you?

Is it possible that you do not have a valid Google JavaScript API key?

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin for jQuery that leverages the Google Translate API. It definately makes things easier and cleaner.

[jquery-translate](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-translate/)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the key and see if it will work for you