# how to remove this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'translatedText' of null "

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have exactly same Question 
[How can I use Google Translate via Ajax using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919522/how-can-i-use-google-translate-via-ajax-using-jquery)
trying to change text using google api .But I am getting this 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'translatedText' of null.
I am trying to get "hello world" in different language  (like french and german).can you please tell me how I will achieve this ?

http://jsfiddle.net/n0217sn0/

```
$.ajax({  
    url: 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/language/translate',  
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: { q: 'Hello world!',  // text to translate
            v: '1.0',
            langpair: 'en|es' },   // '|es' for auto-detect
    success: function(result) {
        alert('dd');
        console.log(result)
        alert(result.responseData.translatedText);
    },  
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, errorMsg, errorThrown) {
                alert('dddd')

        alert(errorMsg);
    }  
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you open the console, and see where it clearly says *`Please use Translate v2`*

Comment: yes I already see that but how I will change the hello text .I also change v:"1.0" to v:"2.0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request you are sending is giving an error:

to check error : try

```
$.ajax({  
    url: 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/language/translate',  
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: { q: 'Hello world!',  // text to translate
            v: '1.0',
            langpair: 'en|es' },   // '|es' for auto-detect
    success: function(result) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(result));

        //console.log(result);
        alert(result.responseData.translatedText);
    },  
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, errorMsg, errorThrown) {
                alert('dddd');

        alert(errorMsg);
    }  
});
```

Code using alternative

```
$.ajax({  
    url: 'http://api.mymemory.translated.net/get',  
    data: { q: 'Hello world!',  // text to translate
            langpair: 'en|es' },   // '|es' for auto-detect
    success: function(result) {

        //console.log(result);
        alert(result.responseData.translatedText);
    },  
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, errorMsg, errorThrown) {
                alert('dddd');

        alert(errorMsg);
    }  
});
```

Detailed Document on 
[API DOC](http://mymemory.translated.net/doc/spec.php)

Comment: version 1 of translate API might be deprecated

Comment: so how I will change the hello text

Comment: it is a paid service refer http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/overview.html

Comment: soo is there any other way to change the text.?

Comment: refer this for alternative http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6151668/alternative-to-google-translate-api

Comment: thanks can you please use any of the method in thread I will thankfull to you.using this http://web.archive.org/web/20110720142541/http://basharkokash.com/post/2010/04/19/Bing-Translator-for-developers.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6151668/alternative-to-google-translate-api ..here written google api is still free

Comment: google's official doc says it is paid. Avoid hacks when there are alternatives

Comment: thanks for help can you use one way which is free ..for translate word

Comment: thank for update ..but at what language it change en is English but what is es ? can you please provide chart

Comment: Please refer document