# Can I send ajax request to translate.google.com from my website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to use google translate on my website AS FREE, Can I do that?
And how can I do that?
below code say:

> `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://translate.google.com/translate_a/single?client=t&sl=auto&tl=en&hl=en…l=0&tsel=3&q=%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%85+%DA%A9%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%A8%D8%B1%DB%8C/f.txt. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.` OR FireBug said: `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://translate.google.com/translate_a/single?client=t&sl=auto&tl=en&hl=en&dt=bd&dt=ex&dt=ld&dt=md&dt=qc&dt=rw&dt=rm&dt=ss&dt=t&dt=at&dt=sw&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&oc=1&otf=2&ssel=0&tsel=3&q=%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%85+%DA%A9%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%A8%D8%B1%DB%8C/f.txt. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.`

How can I enable Cros?

```
  $.ajax({url:"http://translate.google.com/translate_a/single?client=t&sl=auto&tl=en&hl=en&dt=bd&dt=ex&dt=ld&dt=md&dt=qc&dt=rw&dt=rm&dt=ss&dt=t&dt=at&dt=sw&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&oc=1&otf=2&ssel=0&tsel=3&q=%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%85+%DA%A9%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%A8%D8%B1%DB%8C/f.txt"
        ,type: 'GET'
        ,crossDomain: true
        ,dataType: "text"
        ,success:function(result){
            alert(result);
    }});
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It needs to be enabled on the other side. You probably have to use the API or get it in a different way.

Comment: No. This is not offical legal.

Anyway, a user has done it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8543979/2441442

Comment: googles translate api is not a free service https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/pricing you could prob do a scrape with curl but im sure it would be in violation of the tos

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25470486/

Comment: @andrew Tnaks man, that's my asnwer, Thak you very much.

Comment: Daniyal, I noticed you un-accepted my answer. Is there any more info you need, or can I refine my answer in any ways? Feel free to not respond if you don't want to, but if there is any way I can be more helpful, let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something that may help:

In order to interact with google translate from a third party source, like your website, is with the [Google Translate API](https://developers.google.com/translate/).

The API costs about $20 per million characters, and more info can be found on [Pricing and Terms](https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/pricing).

It's possible I misunderstood your question. If you were trying to translate an entire website, you can use the free [Google Website Translator](https://translate.google.com/manager/website/)

Though paying is the only way to access Google Translate, as described above, try the [Yandex](http://api.yandex.com/translate/doc/dg/concepts/api-overview.xml) translate API if you want a free translation API.
Hope this helps!

Comment: @Daniyal is asking about a free solution.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt yes, thanks. I edited the post accordingly.